# What does the lie have got to do with April?

Tags: your-lie-in-april

What does the [lie](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/16889/what-exactly-was-the-lie-in-april) in *Your Lie in April* have to do with April?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Japanese academic year runs from April to March of the following year. *Your Lie in April* opens in April, at the start of the school year, and that's the point when Kaori tells the lie.